# Apple Enterprise Developer to Distribute Ad Hoc To Clients?

Tags: iphone, ipad, deployment, app-store, adhoc

With apples Enterprise developer account will i be able to distribute ad hoc to customers aswell? Or is it only limited to in-house employees?

Ad-hoc deployment will suit our application deployment structure better to our customers, where they will purchase the software from us and we will provide them with the provisioning and ad hoc files to install. But I have a feeling apple wont have a bar of it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that Ad Hoc distribution certificates have an expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do it through the App Store, then Apple don't support your business model.  Enterprise is for in-house distribution, ad hoc is for testing, the App Store is for selling your app.

Your best option is to go through the App Store, but I'm guessing that if you're posting this question, it's probably because you're doing something that violates the App Store guidelines.  Perhaps if you post the reason why you are avoiding the App Store, somebody might be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Reason being is we currently have software the is sold on a concurrent user basis. The figure it is sold for lets say for arguments sake is $500 per concurrent user. Now we will be releasing this software as an IPad app. The problem i have with the app store is someone can purchase this software for whatever price we set it at than just mass deploy it to other devices sharing the same itunes account.

Comment: I don't think that's likely to be a problem.  If a business can afford to buy its staff iPads, then I doubt they would want to deal with that hassle, they'll just spend the money.  If the staff are using their own iPads, they won't want to wipe their iPads to use the shared account.

Comment: In any case, each device has its own unique identifier that is available to your app.  You can determine the number of unique concurrent users through that.

Comment: Well, if you count 5 as a "mass". IIRC, Buying an app lets you install on a max of 5 devices, just like music purchased through iTunes. I suppose if you had a really expensive piece of software it might be a problem but otherwise, not really.

Comment: So purchased apps can only be published to 5 devices max? I would love to just put the app up on the app store for free than when a user logs in the app will check the database to see if there are any licenses free. If there are than one will be taken up by this device using their device id. If there are no licenses than they will need to call us too purchase more. But I dont think apple would approve this since it is getting around their payment system???

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about SaaS or simply a standalone app?  If your app is SaaS, then you are probably fine.  If you are simply trying to restrict a standalone iPad app, you are probably not fine.

Comment: SaaS on IPad? How does this work with a cocoa IPad project? What about apples subscription service, does anyone know if one subscription is transferrable between devices. i.e. App is free but they than pay a subscription for each device??

Comment: @MattyD -- The app is actually attached to the account because it belongs to the user not the device. The license allows the user to install his copy of the app on up to five devices. For example, I have both an iPhone and an iPad and I have several apps that run on both. I need but one license both installs. This works because ALL the devices attributes e.g. contacts, music, all other apps are likewise synced to the user. It would be virtually impossible to actually use an iPad if 5 or more separate users all had to share the same account. You apps are safe.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that the Enterprise distribution is legally restricted to a business internal use. There are restrictions on the number of users and the certificates expire. It's definitely not a "By an Enterprise distribution and then sell as many copies to whomever you wish" sort of arraignment.

I just saw a book: [Enterprise iPhone and iPad Administrator's Guide](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/deployment/9781430230090), that might shed some light on your dilemma.